# Converting from shp to geojson fails

Tags: ogr2ogr, d3, topojson

I'm following Mike Bostock's tutorial, [let's make a map](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/), but for a map of Mexico. I want to display state boundaries.

I was able to get the map of Mexico from Natural Earth Data's world maps. My source for the state boundaries is here:

http://duopixel.com/LIMITE_ESTATAL.shp

NOTE: this should be the same file as [here](http://www.inegi.org.mx/lib/usuarios/default.asp?s=geo&sistema=dinf1m), but INEGI's server seems to be down for days. I was able to convert it from ogr2ogr into geojson. When you convert from geojson into topojson, this notice comes up:

```
duopixel$ topojson -s 5 -o estados_simp.json -- estados.json
quantization: maximum error 78.607km (0.707°)
simplification: retained 1130 / 454450 points (0%)
```

It still seems to generate the file and it looks like it's correct. [This is the file it generates](http://duopixel.com/estados.json). This is my javascript code:

```
d3.json("estados.json", function(error, mex) {

  var estados = mex.objects.estados.geometries

  svg.selectAll(".estado")
    .data(estados)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "estado")
    .attr("d", path)
});
```

However, I get an error when running this code...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Now, since I'm not even sure what I'm doing, I have no idea where the failure point is. I'm stuck at this point and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Careful with the `-s` argument; it takes an area threshold in steradians. A value of 5 steradians is about 40% of the surface of the sphere, which is why it only retained 0% (1130 / 454450) of the input points. For a map of Mexico, you probably want something closer to 1e-8. Alternatively, use `--simplify-proportion` and specify a value between 0 and 1. See the [command line reference](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference) for details.

Answer (score 2):

It was a mistake on my javascript code, I wasn't unpacking the data with the clientside topojson...

```
d3.json("estados.json", function(error, mex) {
  var estados = topojson.object(mex, mex.objects.estados);

  svg.selectAll(".estado")
    .data(estados.geometries)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "estado")
    .attr("d", path);
})
```